# Background facebook login and information retreival in android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I want the following flow of actions:-

1. user presses a sign in button
2. facebook application requests user for permission
3. after user agrees, my application retrieves information from the account and sends it to a server online.

My question is how do I achieve this? I have been fiddling with the login button and custom Ui classes given the facebook sdk tutorial, but I don't want a fragment to be there since I do not even need it.
Any suggestions people?

Answer (score 0):

Add Facebook SDK tou your project and in your main Activity, it goes like this

```
    package com.example.integration;

    import java.util.Arrays;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.facebook.Request;
    import com.facebook.Response;
    import com.facebook.Session;
    import com.facebook.SessionState;
    import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
    import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private LoginButton fbLoginBtn;

        private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

        private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(MainActivity.this, callback);
            uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            fbLoginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
            fbLoginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            if (session != null &&
                    (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
            }

        }

@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

        private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            if (state.isOpened()) {
                Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
                edit.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
                edit.putString("expires", session.getExpirationDate() + "");
                edit.commit();
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                        if (user != null) {
                            String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                            String lastName = user.getLastName();
                            String id = user.getId();
                            String email = (String) user.asMap().get("email");

                            Log.i("facebookid", id);
                            Log.i("firstName", firstName);
                            Log.i("lastName", lastName);
                            Log.i("AccessToken", session.getAccessToken());
                            Log.i("Email", email);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("name", firstName);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }

                });

            } 

            else if (state.isClosed()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(MainActivity.this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

and in your xml you need to add the Facebook Login Button

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        facebook:confirm_logout="false"
        facebook:fetch_user_info="true" />
```

Comment: You didn't specify what context to use SecondActivity and WelcomeActivity

Comment: I replaced WelcomeActivity with MainActivity and created a SecondActivity. Sadly still this doesn't solve my requirements. The logout button is still showing. This is the same thing as facebook android tutorials only without fragments.

Comment: @Aditya Pan SecondActivity is that where you want to go after Completing the Facebook Login. By default Facebook Login button will be turning to Logout Button after logging in. But you will be navigated to SecondActivity after completing Facebook Login.